# Pointing an object at my mouse, but it isn't pointing in the right way

Tags: lua, love2d

So I'm trying to make a circular pong game and I'm making the paddle at the moment

In my main.lua, I have this code inside love.update:

```
pad:update(
function(dt,self)
    local mouseX,mouseY=love.mouse.getPosition()
    self.rot=math.atan2((mouseY - self.y), (mouseX - self.x))
    self.x = circleRadius*math.cos(self.r) + self.orgX;
    self.y = circleRadius*math.sin(self.r) + self.orgY;
    self.r=self.r+.5*dt


end,
dt
)
```

(Paddle.lua, the paddle file, executes the function given by the caller continuously in the update function)

It *does* point towards the mouse, but not in the way I want it to. Currently, it's like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfhk4.jpg) (badly illustrated since snipping tool doesn't capture the mouse so I have to draw where it would be)

Instead, I want it like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQElc.jpg)

The anchor point of the paddle is in the middle as in it's offset on the x and y axis by half the width and height, respectively. (it's a image file, since you can't really rotated love.graphics.rectangle objects)

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rotate additional 90°, replace

```
self.rot=math.atan2((mouseY - self.y), (mouseX - self.x))
```

with

```
self.rot=math.atan2((mouseX - self.x), -(mouseY - self.y))
```